# Use fullCalendar header only

Tags: javascript, python, django, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar for my django project. For some of my template files(HTML files), I want to use only the header of the calendar not the calendar container.
My header will look like this
[image]
I can select month, day, week and with the arrow I can go forward and previous month, day or even week.

Can I use only the header of fullCalendar? if so how can I subtract container of the fullCalendar? Can anyone suggest me a better way to build a calendar header only?

Comment: Let's go back a step...why do you want to show the header without the rest of the calendar? What will that achieve? This seems a strange requirement, so maybe there's actually a better way to achieve your overall goal. Anyway though, if you really want to do that, TBH you'd probably just be quicker to create your own HTML table which shows some day names in a grid.

Comment: I have edited my question. answering to questions: I want to make my own container where there will be no calendar. there will be a table like daily costs of some product.

Comment: But you want to be able to go forward and back between different weeks, I guess? Like the `<` and `>` buttons in fullCalendar?

Comment: What you want is a little different than a normal calendar, then. I suggest you should maybe look at the fullCalendar source code and just take the bits of functionality you need - i.e. to display the header, and handle calculating the new dates to display when the buttons are pressed. It's MIT-licensed, so you can re-use it almost any way you wish. And then replace the rest of the code with your idea to just have a simple table of products with different entries for each day.

Answer (score 0):

'.fc-view-harness': {
display: "none"
}